# UWP - NavigationViewItem - Switch Page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigation, event-handling

I don't know at the moment, even by further research, how to change the pages assigned to the `NavigationView` class by the action of clicking on the `NavigationMenuItems`.

**Note:** I want to only implement code development in C#.

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to create multiple new blank pages, such as BlankPage1,BlankPage2. The process is as follows:
Right click the project->Add->New Item->Blank Page

2.You could get the name of clicked item in [NavigationView.ItemInvoked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.iteminvoked?view=winrt-19041) event, then call [Frame.Navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winrt-19041) method to switch the page. As follows:

XAML code:

```
<Page
   ..>
 
    <Grid>
        <NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Left"  ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems >
                <NavigationViewItem Content="A" x:Name="A" />
                <NavigationViewItem Content="B" x:Name="B" />             
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
        {
            var item = args.InvokedItemContainer;
            switch (item.Name)
            {
                case "A":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
                    break;
case "B":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage2));
                    break;

            }
        }
```